# Why using Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke does not update my GUI but using BeginInvoke does?

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, dispatcher

I am confused about the differences between **Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke** and **BeginInvoke**

I have the following portion of code that didn't work, the code in UpdateCounts method is being ignored:

```
private void Start()
{
    _testResults = new TestResults(ModelNameTextBox.Text);
    _timer = new System.Threading.Timer(UpdateCounts, null, 0, 500);            
}

private void UpdateCounts(object info)
{
    Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
    {
        PassCountLabel.Text = _testResults.PassedCount.ToString();
        RequestCountLabel.Text = _testResults.RequestedCount.ToString();                
    }));
}
```

But once removing Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher, it works fine:

```
private void UpdateCounts(object info)
{
    BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
    {
        PassCountLabel.Text = _testResults.PassedCount.ToString();
        RequestCountLabel.Text = _testResults.RequestedCount.ToString();                
    }));
}
```

Comment: You cannot arbitrarily mix WPF and Winforms code like this.  It looks like your Main() entrypoint used the Winforms version of Application.Run().  Using Dispatcher will then just fail to run any code since there is no dispatcher loop in the app.  If this is *intentional*, in other words this code is in a library and you cannot assume whether it will be a WPF or Winforms app using the library then you have to do it very differently.  You have to copy SynchronizationContext.Current in the constructor.  But then again, updating controls in a library is bad.  Don't mix.

Answer (score 0):

*The*  **Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke** *will work only if you call it from the UI thread,if not it calls the current thread.*

*You have to use* **Application.Current.Dispatcher** *to call the UI thread*.